# How to Store Sub directory in a list c#

Tags: c#

the below code will display all sub-directories contained in the main directory
i need to get the data displayed by method LoadSubDirs(string dir) stored in a list

```
class Program
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string root = @"D:\";
        string[] subdirectories = Directory.GetDirectories(root);

        foreach (string subdir in subdirectories)
        {
            LoadSubDirs(subdir);


        }

    }
    private static void LoadSubDirs(string dir)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(dir);

        try
        {
            string[] subdirectories = Directory.GetDirectories(dir);

            foreach (string subdir in subdirectories)
            {
                try
                {
                    LoadSubDirs(subdir);
                }
                catch { }


            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `List<string> subDirs = Directory.EnumerateDirectories(dir).ToList();`?

Comment: *i need to get the data **displayed** by method LoadSubDirs(string dir) stored in a list*, do you mean to say `return` instead of `display`? If display is correct then what kind of data it displays

Comment: `Directory.GetDirectories(root, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)` will get the subdirectories too, although it will not ignore errors like the code shown does.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is your code, with the directory saved in a List object

```
using System.IO;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string root = @"D:\";
        string[] subdirectories = Directory.GetDirectories(root);
        List<string> listDirs = new List<string>();

        foreach (string subdir in subdirectories)
        {
            LoadSubDirs(subdir, listDirs);
        }

    }
    private static void LoadSubDirs(string dir, List<string> listDirs)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(dir);
        listDirs.Add(dir);

        try
        {
            string[] subdirectories = Directory.GetDirectories(dir);

            foreach (string subdir in subdirectories)
            {
                try
                {
                    LoadSubDirs(subdir, listDirs);
                }
                catch { }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is to use properly recursivity, I think you should do like that.
In my opinion if you "loop" a first time before calling your recursive function you're missing something.
And if you're using a class/struct like FolderStruct here, you keep the "tree", wich can be useful sometimes.

```
   public class FolderStruct
{
    public string FolderName { get; set; }
    public List<FolderStruct> FolderChildren { get; set; }
}
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        FolderStruct FolderTree = new FolderStruct
        {
            FolderName = @"D:\",
            FolderChildren = new List<FolderStruct>()
        };
        LoadSubDirs(FolderTree);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    private static FolderStruct LoadSubDirs(FolderStruct FolderTree)
    {
        try
        {
            string[] subdirectories = Directory.GetDirectories(FolderTree.FolderName);
            if (subdirectories != null)
            {
                foreach (string subdir in subdirectories)
                {
                    var newFolder = new FolderStruct()
                    {
                        FolderName = subdir,
                        FolderChildren = new List<FolderStruct>()
                    };
                    var ret = LoadSubDirs(newFolder);
                    if (ret != null)
                        FolderTree.FolderChildren.Add(ret);
                }
                return FolderTree;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            return null;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

See sample code below :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.IO;

namespace SAveDirectoriesXml
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        const string FOLDER = @"c:\temp";
        static XmlWriter writer = null;
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
            settings.Indent = true;

            writer = XmlWriter.Create(FILENAME, settings);
            writer.WriteStartDocument(true);

            DirectoryInfo info = new DirectoryInfo(FOLDER);
            WriteTree(info);

            writer.WriteEndDocument();
            writer.Flush();
            writer.Close();
            Console.WriteLine("Enter Return");
            Console.ReadLine();

        }
        static long WriteTree(DirectoryInfo info)
        {
            long size = 0;
            writer.WriteStartElement("Folder");
            try
            {
                writer.WriteAttributeString("name", info.Name);
                writer.WriteAttributeString("numberSubFolders", info.GetDirectories().Count().ToString());
                writer.WriteAttributeString("numberFiles", info.GetFiles().Count().ToString());
                writer.WriteAttributeString("date", info.LastWriteTime.ToString());


                foreach (DirectoryInfo childInfo in info.GetDirectories())
                {
                    size += WriteTree(childInfo);
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                string errorMsg = string.Format("Exception Folder : {0}, Error : {1}", info.FullName, ex.Message);
                Console.WriteLine(errorMsg);
                writer.WriteElementString("Error", errorMsg);
            }

            FileInfo[] fileInfo = null;
            try
            {
                fileInfo = info.GetFiles();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                string errorMsg = string.Format("Exception FileInfo : {0}, Error : {1}", info.FullName, ex.Message);
                Console.WriteLine(errorMsg);
                writer.WriteElementString("Error",errorMsg);
            }

            if (fileInfo != null)
            {
                foreach (FileInfo finfo in fileInfo)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        writer.WriteStartElement("File");
                        writer.WriteAttributeString("name", finfo.Name);
                        writer.WriteAttributeString("size", finfo.Length.ToString());
                        writer.WriteAttributeString("date", info.LastWriteTime.ToString());
                        writer.WriteEndElement();
                        size += finfo.Length;
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        string errorMsg = string.Format("Exception File : {0}, Error : {1}", finfo.FullName, ex.Message);
                        Console.WriteLine(errorMsg);
                        writer.WriteElementString("Error", errorMsg);
                    }
                }
            }

            writer.WriteElementString("size", size.ToString());
            writer.WriteEndElement();
            return size;

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How is this answers OP's question. Sorry to say but did you copy this from somewhere, I believe this answer is not what OP is expecting here

Comment: How is this relevant to the question? He wanted to store all sub-directories in a System.Collections.Generic.List instance.

Comment: It is exactly what op asked for.  The OP is recursively going through folder to get file name.  the code above does what OP asked for and includes the Date And size of the file and outputs results into XML format.

Comment: *I need to get the data displayed by method LoadSubDirs(string dir) stored in a list*, where he said to store file size, file name in XML format.. I guess it is just complicating the things

Comment: @jdweng Nope it does not. He wanted to store the displayed data by Console.Write / WriteLine in System.Collections.Generic.List instance that's pretty much it

Comment: So create a class a put the output into a List<> of the class.  Easy to convert.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I've totally overlooked the requirement, but it seems like you are trying to get a list of all sub-directories from `root` and stored them in a `List<string>`.

This code will achieve exactly that without any additional methods or headache:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string root = @"D:\";
    List<string> listDirs = Directory.GetDirectories(root, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).ToList();
}
```

Using `Directory.GetDirectories` with the `SearchOption.AllDirectories` parameter will automatically return all sub-directories as an array of `string`.

Given that you want it as a `List<string>`, use `.ToList()` from Linq to convert the string array to the list. Remember to add `using System.Linq` to your imports.

Answer (score 0):

```
  static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string root = @"D:\";
        List<string> list= Recursive(root);

        foreach (string l in list)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(l);
        }

    }

      static IEnumerable<string> Recursive(string root )
    {

          string[] subdirectories = Directory.GetDirectories(root);
          yield return root;
          if(subdirectories !=null && subdirectories.Length>0)
          {
              foreach(var sub in subdirectories)
              {
                 foreach(var subsub in  Recursive(sub))
                 yield return subsub;
              }   
          }
          else
          {
             yield break;
          }
    }
```